# IOS 7, enable to setup personal hot spot

Tags: iphone, ios, tethering

After Updating latest version of iOS 7. **I am not able to setup personal hot spot in my iPhone 4**.

I use **BSNL (India) carrier**. I was told by the carrier that the problem is an issue with the iPhone update.

I use BSNL for 7 years with a 3G data plan. Until now, I have not had any hot spot related issues but after updating to the latest version of iOS 7 this problem began.

How can I solve this problem? Any hints or suggestions are most welcome.

[image: Cellular waring - Set Up Personal Hotspot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! [Cross-posting](http://superuser.com/questions/734620/ios-7-enable-to-setup-personal-hot-spot) is not allowed — questions should be posted on a single site only and will be migrated to another site if necessary.

Comment: We're you able to use hotspot before? Restart your iPhone and it might display a carrier-update.

Comment: I restart many times and also format and install new version through itunes

Comment: We're you able to use hotspot before?

Comment: in same iPhone 4, its working fine in ios 6.

Answer (score -1):

1. setting- cellular- cellular data network.
2. Cellular data
   apn: test
   username: test
   password: 12345678
3. Personal hotspot
   apn: test
   username: test
   password: 123456789

have good day